# PSQL select key of the first elemen of JSON field

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, psql

I have a table that contains a JSON datatype field. I want to SELECT WHERE a value exists in this JSON field:

```
dev=> select id, command from statemachine_history;

 id  |                                       command                                        
------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1 | {"Common\\Accounting\\StateMachine\\Command\\CreateDebitorCommand":true}
    2 | []
    3 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand":true}
    4 | []
    5 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand":false}
    6 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageCheckRetryCommand":true}
    7 | {"Common\\Newsletter\\Command\\IssueConfirmationRequest":true}
    8 | {"Common\\Customer\\Command\\CustomerActivateCommand":true}
    9 | {"Common\\Customer\\Command\\CustomerRegisterCommand":true}
   10 | {"Common\\Accounting\\StateMachine\\Command\\CreateDebitorCommand":true}
   11 | []
   12 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand":true}
   13 | {"Common\\Accounting\\StateMachine\\Command\\CreateDebitorCommand":true}
 1033 | []
   14 | []
   15 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand":true}
   16 | {"Common\\Customer\\Command\\CustomerActivateCommand":true}
   17 | {"Common\\Customer\\Command\\CustomerRegisterCommand":true}
   18 | []
   19 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand":false}
   20 | {"Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageCheckRetryCommand":true}
   21 | {"INTPASS\\Appointment\\StateMachine\\Command\\FinalizeBookingsCommand":true}
   22 | {"INTPASS\\Appointment\\StateMachine\\Command\\FinalizeBookingsCommand":true}
```

I want to know how to access the key of this array. Specifically, I want to select from this table where some value exists in the command field.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM statemachine_history WHERE command->'key' = 'Common\\Message\\StateMachine\\MessageSendOutCommand'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can change JSON field datatype to string then can use LIKE keyword %%
Example:

```
SELECT identifier FROM statemachine_history WHERE schema_name='Subscription' AND command::varchar LIKE '%ChangeMembershipPlanCommand%'
```